# invalid_auth error with correct Slack Token, while uploading file into Slack

Tags: jenkins, slack

We are unable to upload files into Slack, through this plugin due to invalid_auth error, though the Slack Token provided is valid.

Plugin Name : slack-uploader-plugin

Pending on [jenkins](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-53145?attachmentOrder=desc) since long time anyone has solution regarding this .